# Open application from OSX Terminal with debug printouts

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, terminal, xcode

I can open an application using `open`, like this:

```
open ./MyApp.app
```

But this doesn't display the application's debug printouts - which I need.

If I locate the binary inside the package manually and run that, I get the printouts fine, but I want to be able to just run the application.

Comment: So you don't want to just run the executable backgrounded from bash to see the output? I'm not sure that there's any other way to do this, the .app package is a proprietary Apple design that Bash wouldn't be personally aware of.

Comment: I want the application to run hidden but must also use cocoa. This works fine if I set "Application is agent" in the plist file and run it as an actual application. If I just run the binary directly, it doesn't run hidden and displays the dock+menu components.

Comment: Actually if I run the binary by specifying the path rather than cd-ing to it, it works fine. Cool.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to specify the absolute path of the application, rather than the path relative to the current directory.

For example,
`open /home/matt/MyApp.app`

Comment: This shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 5):

*.app* Applications are directories, from the terminal open the executable rather than the whole directory, e.g...

```
open /Applications/my.app/Contents/MacOS/my
```

If you're not sure of the executable file name within the app contents, inspect *my.app/Contents/Info.plist* `CFBundleExecutable`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no debug or verbose flag for the open command.

You can view your application's Warning or Error output using `console.app`.

[image: console.app]

Alternatively if your application has debug or verbosity flags, you can pass the flag to your application using `open --args`. For example, Google Chrome has the flags `--enable-logging --v=1` to turn on debugging and save the output to `chrome_debug.log` in the Chrome user data directory. You can launch Google Chrome with the following options

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --enable-logging --v=1
```

Options for `open` command

```
 -a application
     Specifies the application to use for opening the file

 -b bundle_indentifier
     Specifies the bundle identifier for the application to use when open-
     ing the file

 -e  Causes the file to be opened with /Applications/TextEdit

 -t  Causes the file to be opened with the default text editor, as deter-
     mined via LaunchServices

 -f  Reads input from standard input and opens the results in the default
     text editor.  End input by sending EOF character (type Control-D).
     Also useful for piping output to open and having it open in the
     default text editor.

 -F  Opens the application "fresh," that is, without restoring windows.
     Saved persistent state is lost, except for Untitled documents.

 -W  Causes open to wait until the applications it opens (or that were
     already open) have exited.  Use with the -n flag to allow open to
     function as an appropriate app for the $EDITOR environment variable.

 -R  Reveals the file(s) in the Finder instead of opening them.

 -n  Open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already run-
     ning.

 -g  Do not bring the application to the foreground.

 -j  Launches the app hidden.

 -h  Searches header locations for a header whose name matches the given
     string and then opens it.  Pass a full header name (such as NSView.h)
     for increased performance.

 -s  For -h, partial or full SDK name to use; if supplied, only SDKs whose
     names contain the argument value are searched. Otherwise the highest
     versioned SDK in each platform is used.

 --args
     All remaining arguments are passed to the opened application in the
     argv parameter to main().  These arguments are not opened or inter-
     preted by the open tool.
```